# My login form is not working in Android. What might be the cause?

Tags: java, android, authentication, passwords

I am making a login page for an app and I am making a login screen for the app. But, my login is not working at all.
So, as far as I am concerned, my code is pretty okay. But why is not doing anything when pressing the Login button. What is the error? No toasts or any other pages open up, even when I put in the correct username and password!

```
public class MainPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText uName, pass;
    Button loginBtn;

    //ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mybackground);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
        setTitle("Q-GAX");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.abs_layout);

        loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        uName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uName);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
        loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (uName.getText().toString().equals("admin") && pass.getText().toString().equals("pass")) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                            TasksPanel.class);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }     
            }
        });
        //myImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progressanimation);

        //AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) myImageView.getBackground();

        // Start the animation (looped playback by default).
        //frameAnimation.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.leaveMode) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Leave Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (id == R.id.officeMode) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Office Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (id == R.id.meetingMode) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Meeting Mode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (id == R.id.faq) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App FAQ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your "if" condition might be returning false.Since you not added ".show()" in the toast the toast won't appear.

Comment: @benid you said `even when I put in the correct username and password!` . is it changing your screen?

Comment: Yup. It's going to the next activity now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add **`.show()`**. Read [**`Toast`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

> Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();

```
if (uName.getText().toString().equals("admin") && pass.getText().toString().equals("pass")) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainPage.this, TasksPanel.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    finish();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Username or Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks :) I really should pay more attention to my code. It was such a simple issue.

Comment: @Tej looks like its a dummy test

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
 {          
    if(uName.getText().toString().equals("admin") && pass.getText().toString().equals("pass"))
    {
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainPage.this, TasksPanel.class);
     startActivity(myIntent);
     finish();
    }
    else
    {  
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Username or Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
```